# Log4J Integration for Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

I am using an embedded jetty and `log4j`. In my project I have `log4j.properties` file for managing my logs. It looks like the following:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog =DEBUG, consoleAppender

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, consoleAppender, fileAppender
```

The problem is that the first line, which should define jetty's log level does not work. Due to my rootlogger I get the message

```
INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - Logging initialized @11716ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
```

additionally, I tried:

```
log4j.category.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
```

So jetty seems to detect slf4jlog and the root logging is working. Now I want to write a special log level for jetty. If I only put the first line to `log4j.properties` then I do not get any output. I also tried to prefix the firstline with log4j: `log4j.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog =DEBUG, consoleAppender` which is still not working. I simply do not get any output....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog =DEBUG, consoleAppender
```

The class `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog` has no debug level logging events on that logger name.
You will not see DEBUG level logging events on that logger name.

That's just a bridge class from Jetty logging facade to Slf4j logging facade (which then routes to your Log4J implementation).

Each instance of `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog` will have a specific declared logger name that those events will be emitted on.

Have you tried just ....

```
log4j.category.org.eclipse.jetty=DEBUG, consoleAppender
```

That will put all loggers that start with `org.eclipse.jetty` into `DEBUG` level appending to your configured logger called `consoleAppender`

Comment: I have to write log4j.category.org.eclipse.jetty=DEBUG, consoleAppender; If you change your post I wll accept it!